# Reversing characters from argument of the program

Tags: disassembly, binary-analysis

Below code is from the IDA.

This is the code before the parsing function:

```
movzx   eax, byte ptr [rbp+nineth_char+3]
movsx   eax, al
mov     edi, eax
call    sub_898
```

And this is the code of the parsing function:

```
push    rbp
mov     rbp, rsp
mov     eax, edi
mov     [rbp+var_14], al
movsx   eax, [rbp+var_14]
mov     [rbp+var_1], al
mov     [rbp+var_2], 250
movzx   edx, [rbp+var_1]
movzx   eax, [rbp+var_2]
add     eax, edx
nop
pop     rbp
retn
```

The argument of this function is the ascii value of the nineth char from the argument of the binary file. This value is added to the value from [rbp+var_2] which is 250. And this function returns the result of the adding.

This is the code after the parsing function:

```
mov     edx, eax
movzx   eax, [rbp+var_35] ; 101
cmp     dl, al
jz      short loc_F6
```

Result is compared with 101 value and when ZF flag is set the processor will jump to the next label.

The equation is: ascii_value_of_char + 250 = 101, but the ascii value of character can't be a negative number. So is my understanding of this code is good or not? If not, could you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it compares only one byte of the result (sizes of the compared **al** and **dl** parts of the corresponding registers are 8 bits). This makes your equation a bit different:

```
(ascii_value_of_char + 250) & 0xff = 101
```

Which is definitely solvable, and the ascii value of char in this case is 'k'. You can see the difference between rax, eax, dh and dl for example [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/X86_Architecture).